# How to select last 25% of dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question given to us was 'Display all the distinct orders where the quantity is in the bottom quartile'.

I tried the following

```
USE [Northwind]
GO

DECLARE @maxValue int
SELECT @maxValue = MAX(Quantity) FROM [Order Details]

SELECT OrderID, ProductID, (Quantity / @maxValue) AS 'tot'
FROM [Order Details] AS od
WHERE 'tot' <= 0.25
ORDER BY ProductID
GO
```

output should look like this

[image: output should look like this]

What am I doing wrong in my script?

Comment: A side note, the `'tot'` in the `WHERE` clause is literal string not a column name. Remove the `''` or make them double quotoes `"tot"`

Comment: Try making `@maxValue` as `DECIMAL` or use `((Quantity *1.0) / @maxValue)`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to `DECIMAL` first and then do a match
Something like this.`((Quantity *1.0) / @maxValue)`

```
DECLARE @maxValue DECIMAL(18,2)
SELECT @maxValue = MAX(Quantity) FROM [Order Details]
SELECT OrderID, ProductID, ((Quantity *1.0) / @maxValue) AS 'tot'
FROM [Order Details] AS od
WHERE ((Quantity *1.0) / @maxValue) <= 0.25
ORDER BY ProductID
```

You can optionally use a `WHERE` clause like this `WHERE Quantity <= (@maxValue * 0.25 )`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going `(Quantity / @maxValue)<=0.25` instead of 'tot'?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `WINDOWED functions` to achieve that. You won't have to query your [Order Details] table twice. Please try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT od.OrderID, od.ProductID, ((od.Quantity * 1.00) / MAX(od.Quantity) OVER())) AS tot
    FROM [Order Details] AS od
    ) AS T
WHERE T.tot <= 0.25
ORDER BY T.ProductID;
```

But your description says, that you're looking for bottom Quartile, thus making me think that `NTILE()` would be a better approach for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT od.OrderID, od.ProductID, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY od.Quantity) AS Quartile
    FROM [Order Details] AS od
    ) AS T
WHERE T.Quartile = 1
ORDER BY T.ProductID;
```

Comment: I "SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT od.OrderID, od.ProductID, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY od.Quantity) AS Quartile
    FROM [Order Details] AS od
    ) AS T
WHERE T.Quartile = 1
ORDER BY T.ProductID;" but it does not give the desired result. It gives back 539 results and they are looking for 263 results

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem.

```
USE Northwind
GO

SELECT DISTINCT a.OrderID, a.ProductID
FROM [Order Details] as a
WHERE Quantity <= (SELECT AVG(Quantity * 0.25
             FROM [Order Details]
             WHERE a.ProductID = ProductID)
GO
```